# What is the runtime complexity of using beginning-of-line?

Tags: performance

I did a test where going to from the end to the beginning of a 50 million length line happens instantly when using **beginning-of-line**. I wonder if this is because it is a C primitive or because Emacs implements this and related functions in an efficient way. For example, it could keep a mapping from line numbers to the positions of those lines within the buffer (this is just a guess). Why is it so fast? Does the runtime depend on the number of characters on the line, or is it constant?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underlying function is `find_newline` in `emacs/src/search.c`. It uses a cache of sections of text that contain no newlines, so the function can skip over them quickly. The cache is controlled by the variable `cache-long-scans`, whose doc string says:

> Non-nil means that Emacs should use caches in attempt to speedup buffer scans.
>
> There is no reason to set this to nil except for debugging purposes.
>
> Normally, the line-motion functions work by scanning the buffer for
> newlines.  Columnar operations (like ‘move-to-column’ and
> ‘compute-motion’) also work by scanning the buffer, summing character
> widths as they go.  This works well for ordinary text, but if the
> buffer’s lines are very long (say, more than 500 characters), these
> motion functions will take longer to execute.  Emacs may also take
> longer to update the display.
>
> If ‘cache-long-scans’ is non-nil, these motion functions cache the
> results of their scans, and consult the cache to avoid rescanning
> regions of the buffer until the text is modified.  The caches are most
> beneficial when they prevent the most searching---that is, when the
> buffer contains long lines and large regions of characters with the
> same, fixed screen width.
>
> When ‘cache-long-scans’ is non-nil, processing short lines will
> become slightly slower (because of the overhead of consulting the
> cache), and the caches will use memory roughly proportional to the
> number of newlines and characters whose screen width varies.
>
> Bidirectional editing also requires buffer scans to find paragraph
> separators.  If you have large paragraphs or no paragraph separators
> at all, these scans may be slow.  If ‘cache-long-scans’ is non-nil,
> results of these scans are cached.  This doesn’t help too much if
> paragraphs are of the reasonable (few thousands of characters) size.
>
> The caches require no explicit maintenance; their accuracy is
> maintained internally by the Emacs primitives.  Enabling or disabling
> the cache should not affect the behavior of any of the motion
> functions; it should only affect their performance.